# Order-preserving operations on expectation of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation

I'm curious about the following situation.  Suppose we have two stochastic processes, $\{X_t\},$ and $\{Y_t\},$ which satisfy the expectation ordering $E[X_t] \leq E[Y_t],$ for all $t.$

What kind of operations $\phi$ may I apply to the processes such that the transformed processes $\{\phi(X_t)\}$ and $\{\phi(Y_t)\}$ satisfy $E[\phi(X_t)] \leq E[\phi(Y_t)].$

It is apparent that if $\{X_t\},$ and $\{Y_t\}$ were pointwise ordered, i.e. $X_t(\omega) \leq Y_t(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ in the sample space and all $t,$ then $\phi$ can be an arbitrary monotone increasing function.

Additionally, if $\phi$ is a sign-preserving linear map, linearity of expectation helps the inequality pass through.

One might expect there to be a class of $\phi$ which is more general than linear maps, but less general than arbitrary monotone increasing functions for which the above holds.  As a particular example, does the above hold for $\phi(z) = \exp(z)$?  I can't seem to determine this, either way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems direct to **disprove** your conjecture when $\phi$ is not linear.

Comment: I did some more thinking on this since yesterday, and I don't believe the answer is direct.

In particular, it seems to be a joint property of the sample space, the probability measure, and the particular function under consideration.  I'll try to write up an edit (or an answer) with more detail on this later to close it, but if you condition on $\{X_t \leq Y_t\},$ it makes the situation clear.

Answer (score 1):

Without further assumptions on your stochastic processes, you cannot improve on the linear functions.

It suffices to look at one timestep; we want to show that if $$\mathbb{E}[X]\leq\mathbb{E}[Y]\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]\leq\mathbb{E}[\phi(Y)]$$ then $\phi$ is linear.

Suppose $Y=\mathbb{E}[X]$ a.s.  Certainly $\mathbb{E}[X]\leq\mathbb{E}[Y]$, so that $$\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]\leq\mathbb{E}[\phi(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[\phi(\mathbb{E}[X])]=\phi(\mathbb{E}[X])$$  Thus $\phi$ satisfies reverse Jensen's inequality, and so must be convex down (concave).  Reversing the roles of $Y$ and $X$, the function $\phi$ must also be convex (up).

But the only function that is both convex up and convex down is linear.